# Batch Script / CMD / .bat (Error : Application not found )

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Batch Script was working fine but today it randomly started giving an error while using `start` command.

The Code I Have Used

```
@echo off
start https://www.youtube.com
exit
```

Batch File Is Giving a Error Saying :

```
https://www.youtube.com
Application not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so confused at first but after posting the question I opened settings to do a bit research on the issue and I found out there is no default browser chosen. I set chrome as default browser and now it has seem to fix the issue. If anyone else is facing the same issue maybe this will help you !